# admob -> ad network mediation with adfonic

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I am getting error while using adfonic in admob. i am getting following error.

Cannot find adapter class 'com.google.ads.mediation.adfonic.AdfonicAdapter'. Did you link the ad network's mediation adapter? Skipping ad network.

detailed exception is bellow.

```
        Cannot find adapter class 'com.google.ads.mediation.adfonic.AdfonicAdapter'. Did you link the ad network's mediation adapter? Skipping ad network.
    The following was caught and handled:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.mediation.adfonic.AdfonicAdapter
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
        at com.google.ads.g.a(SourceFile:133)
        at com.google.ads.i.run(SourceFile:116)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/ads/mediation/adfonic/AdfonicAdapter
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.mediation.adfonic.AdfonicAdapter
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        ... 14 more        Cannot find adapter class 'com.google.ads.mediation.adfonic.AdfonicAdapter'. Did you link the ad network's mediation adapter? Skipping ad network.
    The following was caught and handled:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.mediation.adfonic.AdfonicAdapter
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
        at com.google.ads.g.a(SourceFile:133)
        at com.google.ads.i.run(SourceFile:116)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/ads/mediation/adfonic/AdfonicAdapter
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.mediation.adfonic.AdfonicAdapter
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: Basic question: Did you add adfonic library??

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the Adfonic mediation adapter in your app. Include that and it will work.